# What is called a language-country prefix like "en-US"?

Tags: locale, translation

I looking for the proper name for the `en-US`, `pt-BR`, etc thing.
I tried searching for a few terms, I've found "[LCID](https://www.google.com/search?q=LCID)" but it seems to be a Windows/Microsoft universe thing.

I'm looking for a better term to describe it, but I'm not quite satisfied with:

- localeCode
- localeSlug

the *language-LOCALE* `[a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}` pattern seems to be used everywhere, so I want to refer to it with a name that implies the format.

Comment: See wiki page for [IETF language tag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag) *defined by the Internet Engineering Task Force in the BCP 47 document series, which is currently composed of normative RFC 5646  and RFC 4647, along with the normative content of the IANA Language Subtag Registry*.

Answer (score 3):

That specific format is the IETF language tag. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5646

You could more generally call it a "language code" or "language tag".